# spacemacs shift + tab does not <backtab> and says that <backtab> is undefined

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am on linux and using a standard keyboard.

i'm not able to use `shift-tab` at all for some reason.  of course i can use `<` but not while in editing mode.  i've looked online but i'm not able to find a solution for the backtab.

am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What does `C-h k` tell you when you press and hold Shift and then hit Tab?

Comment: it says that backtab was translated from S-iso-lefttab, but making a key binding to any of these yields th same result: <backtab> is undefined, any idea?